# How to find +/- uncertainty with a least squares regression

Tags: regression, uncertainty

I have a set of data points with an uncertainty on each point. From these data points I can fit a line, who's which the slope is a significant value. How do I use the information I have to get an estimate on the $ \sigma $ of my final value? All I can find online is information on $ R^2$ and $ \chi ^2 $. Bonus points if there's an easy way to do it in python/numpy/scipy.

Comment: Which final value?  Are you trying to find the standard error of the regression coefficient?

Comment: In the regression context, a datapoint is a (p+1)-uple $(y_i,x_i)$. From your formulation it is not clear whether you mean uncertainty on the $x_i$'s (rhs variables), $y_i$'s or both?

Comment: @ClarkW.Griswold Yes, I'm sorry I wasn't clearer about it in my question. Although, I'm not sure I know the distinction between standard error and other types of error, nor can I tell you any distinguishing characteristics of the type of error I'm looking for besides that it's the value that goes after the +/- in my answer.

Comment: @user603: there is uncertainty on both the $x_i$'s and the $y_i$'s, and they are around the same magnitude. Does that make a big difference?

Comment: Yes! Have a look at [Deming's regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deming-regression) orthogonal least square, total least square, errors in variables model ect. Plenty of good examples to illustrate that this feature of your data (uncertainty in the X's) dramatically biases the OLS coefficients.

Comment: Are the errors of $(y_i,x_i)$ independent and indetically distributed with $(y_k,x_k)$ for $k \not = i$

Comment: Use principle components analysis as the most basic errors in variables model.

Comment: You should change the question - as "least squares regression" is used to describe predicting/explaining $ y $ for a given value of $ x $.  "Errors in variables" or "measurement error" is usually a better term if $ x $ has error as well as $ y $.

Answer (score 1):

You could treat it like a multiple imputation problem.  Basically you just specify distributions to characterize your uncertainty for each point, then you take several draws of your dataset.  Fit your model to each set of draws.  You then average the coefficients, average the variance-covariance matrices, and add a non-negative correction to the VCV's to reflect how different the models are from one another.

I find Gelman's treatment of it to be quite readable at the intro-level.  The formulas are at the end in the section on combining multiple imputations:

www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/missing.pdf

One wrinkle:  is the noise non-independent?  Does error in one point predict error in another?  If so, you need to specify a joint distribution in order to use MI, and take a draw from the multivariate pdf.  This would be trickier.

Edit:  MI gives you properly-inflated SE's.  I'm not sure how you'd use it to get an inflated $\sigma$

Comment: I will look at that link later when I have more time, but it explains specifically what correction to add to my covariance matrix? And how to go from the covariance matrix to a single number for uncertainty? (Numpy automatically calculated a covariance matrix for me, but I have no idea how to use it).

Comment: When you ask about the non-independence of the noise, I assume you talking about non-independence of a one source of error after multiple measurements. The errors might be somewhat dependent, but if I ignore that dependency I am just overestimating my error somewhat, right? Because I have no idea how to estimate how much of the error is non-independent.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a linear estimator $\mathbf{\hat{y}} = \mathbf{X\theta}$ fitted with linear regression $\mathbf{\theta} = (\mathbf{X^\top X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^\top \mathbf{y}$.

If $\mathbf{C}_y = \mathrm{diag}(\sigma_1^2,\sigma_2^2,\ldots,\sigma_m^2)$ is the covariance for the observations $\mathbf{y}$, the covariance for $\mathbf{\theta}$ is given by (see the lemma):

$$
\mathbf{C}_\theta = (\mathbf{X^\top X})^{-1}\mathbf{X^\top C}_y \mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X^\top X})^{-1}
$$

### Lemma

The covariance of a linear mapping $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{Ax} + \mathbf{b}$ is $\mathbf{C}_y = \mathbf{AC}_x\mathbf{A^\top}$ with $\mathbf{C}_x$ the covariance for $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: This is the variance given $ X $.  I think its errors in variables that's wanted.